# How to deal with Around[list] not evaluating if the list elements have Around Head instead of being numeric?

Tags: data, error-propagation, uncertainty

## Background

I like using [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) for data analysis so I can easily keep track of measurement spread and uncertainties. It also automatically produces plots with error bars.

I can define intrinsic uncertainties by hand

```
Around[42, 1.234]
```

[image]

and I can estimate spread and uncertainty and from the data variance.

```
Around@Range[9] 
(* Around[5, 2.73]*)
```

## Problem

However, if I want to do both combined , *i.e.* if I evaluate expressions of the form `Around[{__Around}]` like

```
Around[
    {Around[1., 1.], Around[2., 1.], Around[3., 1.], Around[4., 1.]}
] 

(* Around[{Around[1., 1.], Around[2., 1.], Around[3., 1.], Around[ 4., 1.]}] *)
```

Evaluation returns unchanged.

My expectation is that it should have returned an expression similar to

```
Around[m, err]
```

where `m` is the mean of the data and `err` is an error estimation that takes into account the standard deviation of the data as well as the uncertainty of each point.

## Questions

**How can we fix `Around` so it can do both combined?**

**Is this intended behaviour (with solid technical argument) or a bug?**

## Due Diligence

I couldn't find previous questions about this issue on this site, or the broader web.

It seems to me that the documentation doesn't mention this limitation. It does list the usage but doesn't even give examples of that usage.

[image]

Around was introduced in v12, but I have tested this problem only on [`$Version`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Version.html) 13.2.0 for Linux (W.Cloud) and 13.1.0 for Windows (W.Engine).

```
 $Version
 (* 13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022) *)
 (* 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022) *)
```

---

## In response to answers

My own answer extends the the definition of `Around`, but it doesn't answer if this behaviour is intended and supported by some good technical reason.

As pointed out on @JasonB 's [nice answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282092/10397), [`MeanAround`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeanAround.html) does not have the problem I mention, but the use case is different. While [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) promises to calculate [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) and [`StandardDeviation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html), `MeanAround` calculates a *weighted mean* and *standard error of the mean*. Related but not the same meaning.

#### `MeanAround`

[image]

#### `Around`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

## Comment

The documentation says that

> [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)`[list]`
> gives an approximate object around the mean of the elements of list
> and with an uncertainty corresponding to their standard deviation.

There is no problem using [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) or [`StandardDeviation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardDeviation.html) with a list of `Around` items

```
StandardDeviation[
    Around[#, 1] & /@ Range[9]
] 
(* Around[2.7386127875258306`, 0.40397332145136067`] *)

Mean[
    Around[#, 1] & /@ Range[9]
] 
(* Around[5., 0.3333333333333333] *)
```

So it's not really clear to me why we have this limitation.

## Solution

The solution, however, is quite simple. Just define exactly what the documentation says for this particular argument case.

```
Unprotect[Around];
Around[{q__Around}]:=Around[Mean[{q}], StandardDeviation[{q}]]
Protect[Around];
```

## Analysis

Now `Around` works as expected:

```
Around[
      {Around[1., 1.], Around[2., 1.], Around[3., 1.], Around[4., 1.]}
]  
(* Around[2.5`, 1.3844373104863457`] *)
```

This gives the correct answer for the error estimation, as it can be seen by evaluating the following symbolic expression

```
Around[
    {Around[a, b], Around[c, d]}
]
```

[image]

## Answer from Wolfram Support

I created a support case and the core of their answer was this:

> I can't see anything in the Documentation for Around that would
> suggest that `Around[{Around[...], Around[...]}]` is an expected
> input.
>
> However, I have sent a suggestion report to the appropriate people in
> our development team (with the code you sent) so this can be
> considered for future versions of *Mathematica*.

The answer was quick, I just forgot until now to update this answer.

I don't find this answer satisfactory. While the Wolfram Support statement is true, the description of `Around`'s behavior is general. It should apply to all cases, unless exceptions are listed. One shouldn't expect explicit cases to be listed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [`MeanAround`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeanAround.html) is the function to use when you have a list and want to represent its mean with uncertainty:

```
In[3]:= MeanAround[{Around[1., 1.], Around[2., 1.], Around[3., 1.], 
  Around[4., 1.]}]

Out[3]= Around[2.5, 0.5]
```

I don't really know what `Around[{__Real}]` returns. I don't see a documentation example for [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) that takes a single list of scalars as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for `MeanAround` (+1) somehow it skipped my radar. What do you mean by *" don't see a documentation example for Around that takes a single list of scalars as the first argument."* [It is documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html#:~:text=list%20(list,list%5D%5D) *"`Around[list]` (list of elements) `Around[Mean[list],StandardDeviation[list]]`"*

Comment: The use case for `MeanAround ` is different though, because it makes a weighted `Mean` and calculates the standard error of the mean, not the `StandardDeviation`.

Comment: @rhermans - I saw the usage you mention, but looking through the doc page I did not see an example. I admit I don't understand the different use cases. If you think that `Around[{__Around}]` should be supported, you should definitely send in feedback through the official channels.  Not every developer indulges their short-attention-span by regularly scanning the stack exchange like I do.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I think I'm no longer entitled to support, as I'm no longer in the institution that used to give me site licenses. Currently I'm limited to free Wolfram Cloud and Wolfram Engine.

Comment: On [this page](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=Feedback) you can report a bug or suggestion, and the license information does not have the little asterisk marking it as required information. I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks, `[CASE:5012051]` created.